# tamanho imagem consoante tamanho ecrã

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma dúvida numa pagina HTML que criei.

Toda a página consoante o ecrã grande ou pequeno ele ajusta automaticamente o tamanho. 
Agora a única coisa que não consigo fazer o mesmo é a Imagem.

Será que me conseguem ajudar?

CSS:

```
.image {
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.image img {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/Logo.png" />
```

Comment: Percebo pouco de *html* e *css* para arriscar uma resposta, no entanto julgo que falta indicar `height: x%;` e `width: y%;` onde x e y são os valores em percentagem do espaço que a imagem deve ocupar na *div* que a contém. Note que a *div* tem também de ter as suas dimensões definidas.

Answer (score 1):

A lógica é a mesma que você deve ter usado com os outros elementos, utilizando os valores em porcentagem. Caso você tenha uma imagem assim:

```
<img src="image.png" class="image" />
```

Perceba que o código que você fez em CSS não irá funcionar, pois a regra vai ser aplicada aos elementos `img` **dentro** de elementos `.image`. Para o resultado esperado, é necessário a inversão dos elementos na regra, tendo a regra aplicada a todos os elementos `img` que contenham a classe `.image`.

Logo, podemos ter uma imagem assim:

```
<img src="image.png" class="image" />
```

Com o seguinte CSS:

```
img.image {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtqh98wn/

Comment: a só um problema que não consigo entender. Quando faço diminuir o Browser acrescenta-me uma espaço por cima da imagem uma especie de border ou margin

Comment: Dependendo do tamanho do navegador? Ou você coloca uma margem com porcentagem (o que é _bem_ relativo), ou você se aventura com as _media queries_. As media queries são regras CSS que são aplicadas aos elementos quando certa condição é verdadeira, e uma das mais utilizadas é a `screen`, que é sobre a tela do dispositivo.

Comment: Acontece em qualquer browser. Assim que faço diminuir a página cria-me um espaço em branco ate iniciar a página. No página no total nunca acontece.